# Transforming acceleration to a world reference

Tags: signal-analysis

I have a acceleration data relative to the sensor's coordinate and the sensor's rotation relative to the world coordinate.How can I transform the acceleration from the sensor's coordinate to the world's coordinate?

Comment: Using coordinate transformations.

Comment: Matrix multiplication